# crontab does not execute a simple shell scripts to turn swap off and turn swap back on

Tags: cron, swap

When I execute `swapoff -a && swapon -a` that works like a charm and when I create a scriptfile swap.sh and I run that it works great too.

`chmod 755 swap.sh`

But when I make a crontab that should execute the script, than nothing happens.

`crontab -e`

0 2 * * * /scripts/swap.sh

Am I missing something here?

Comment: probably permission issues

Comment: did you check the logs?

Comment: did you run it with `sudo`?

Comment: The script is run as root.

Comment: yes, I checked the logs

Comment: no I did not run sudo

Answer (score 0):

Since you confirmed the script is running as super user (sudo) and the file has permissions to execute the problem is other thing (cron in this case):

Try using the full path

```
/sbin/swapoff -a && /sbin/swapon -a
```

You have to use full absolute pathnames in crontab commands because when cron runs a script, it does not perform initial login activity (which is where the path(s) are set).

All credits go to: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1766875.html